# keep menu open on hovering over a link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 3 and I am trying to display a horizontal flyout menu when the user hovers over the link:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="md-extension"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu abcdef" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<style>
  .abcdef li {
      float: left;
  }

  #dropdownMenu1:hover + ul.dropdown-menu, ul.dropdown-menu:hover, ul.dropdown-menu li:hover  {
      display: block;
  }
</style>
```

When I hover over the link, the flyout menu does display horizontally. However, when I attempt to hover over one of the list items, the menu disappears. I want the menu to remain open so the user can click on one of the items.

I "display: block" for the dropdown over hovering various elements, but still the menu does not remain open.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the CSS only solution. How it works: first you attach hover to the `.dropdown` div instead of the link itself and then using pseudo class create an invisible space between the link and the dropdown menu.

```
.dropdown:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;  
      bottom: -10px;
      height: 10px;
      width: 100%;
      left: 0;
      display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover > ul.dropdown-menu  {
      display: block;
}
```

[Example](http://www.bootply.com/AJy6vBVRPs)

Answer (score 0):

Like @sherif said. Javascript is your friend here. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/scn9p2gu/2/

Html:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle " id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    <span class="md-extension">hello</span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu abcdef" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.abcdef li {
      float: left;
  }

.theclass {
    display: block;
}
```

JS:

```
$("#dropdownMenu1").hover(
    function() {
            $("ul.dropdown-menu").addClass("theclass");
            $("#dropdownMenu1").addClass("theclass");
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("ul.dropdown-menu").removeClass("theclass");
                $("#dropdownMenu1").removeClass("theclass"); 
            }, 3000);
    }
);
```

Comment: Your example has the same issue as mine. When you hover and move down quickly, the menu disappears.

Comment: Hrm. I am on safari and it seemed to be working. I'll check it on chrome and issue a fix.

Comment: @Donato There we go! Fixed with a 3000 millisecond timeout to remove the dropdown.

Answer (score -1):

you can achieve this using js if you want ... [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/0j94f5e6/)

```
$(function () {
    $(".dropdown").hover(function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeIn("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    }, function () {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop(true, true).fadeOut("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```